# UIView inside UIScrollView becoming touch-unresponsive with iOS 7.1

Tags: ipad, uiview, uiscrollview, ios7.1

I am developing an iPad app which presents to the user a set of zoomable pages. There is a (paged) `UIScrollView` used for scrolling between pages, and each page consists of another `UIScrollView` which allows pinch&zoom, and contains as subview the actual page content which is a custom `UIView` subclass with `CALayer` drawings.

Everything was working fine as of iOS 7.0.x. Unfortunately, when running the app on iPads updated to iOS 7.1, the pages'`UIView` is completely unresponsive to touch events: none of the `UIGestureRecognizer`s attached to it is ever fired, `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` methods are never called, and even pinch gestures that should be captured by the parent ScrollView are not recognized anymore if they happen inside the `UIView`'s bounds (outside of it, they work).

When i set to NO the parent Scrollviews' `scrollEnabled` property, the touch events properly reach the `UIView` but of course this is not the behavior I need.

Apple documentation doesn't say anything about changes in `UIKit` framework, and I also have no clue on how to debug this, since on previous iOS releases everything was working as expected.

Any idea?

**Edit 31/03/2014:**

I was able to do some more debug, and noted that if I omit to add to the `UIView`'s `CALayer` a couple of sublayers (that come from two custom subclasses of `UIView`), the problem doesn't occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving my issue.

What I did was to stop adding the `CALayer`s as sub-layers to the `UIVIew`, and instead adding the `CALayer`s' parent views as sub-views to the main `UIView`.

I still have no idea on why this is happening in 7.1, given that no changes from 7.0 was mentioned in the documentation for this topic.

Anyhow, hope this can help...